# ec2 stack does not update on reboot

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I have an EC2 instance which uses a cloudFormation template for it's settings. My EC2 instance has tomcat on it. I am using my ec2 instance to deploy war files to tomcat.

My process of releasing new code to the ec2 instance is to :

1. Deploy the war file into my s3 bucket.
2. Update my CloudFormation template parameters to have the new war file name. This parameter is then used in the CloudFormation template to pick up the new war file from the s3 bucket.
3. In the CloudFormation console I hit update stack.
4. Then reboot the machine using the ec2 console.

I have found that when I reboot the ec2 instance it does not deploy the new war file and run the template again. Instead I have to stop the instance and then start the instance again (which is very slow).

It was my belief that this would be rebooting the instance should be enough. Am I wrong or have I just got something configured incorrectly?

regards

Comment: It's certainly possible you have something configured incorrectly. If you share more details by providing your CloudFormation template and/or startup script(s) in your question, someone might be able to provide a more specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many CloudFormation features are only updated when the instance is "replaced" look in the documentation for the type you are using to install the file from s3

Under properties it will say "Update requires" and then a condition such as "some interruption" or "replacement"

The s3 file install needs to be controlled by a type property that has a "update requires" condition of "no interruption" then the change will happen instantly after you alter the cloudformation template

Comment: thank you. I'm going to have a look into this setting in my template.